# Entity Framework reverse engineering

Tags: entity-framework, ef-power-tools

Is it possible to ignore certian views and schema tables when generating the poco using entityframework reverse engineering templates.

Comment: As far as I know, reverse engineering templates are not a feature of Visual Studio or Entity Framework. Are you using EF Power Tools?

Comment: Yes, I am using EF power tools. Is it possible to update templates and ignore some views in dbo schema and certian tables?

Comment: I have never used that tool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can use the "entity framework reverse poco generator" available at visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838

Watch the video.